# Is it ok to send the Client Secret as nonce?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, single-page-application

I am building an SPA that connects to my Backend API and I have to integrate Azure AD Login, I am slightly confused about the entire authorization flow. I am trying to be as secure as possible. I will explain the flow below:

1. I build the url in the backend (containing the tenant id and other info), which is returned to the SPA to be added on a button.
2. The user clicks the button, is redirected to the Microsoft/Company authentication page.
3. If the authentication is successful, the user is redirected back to the SPA together with the ID Token.
4. The SPA takes the ID Token and sends it as a Bearer Token on each request to the API.
5. The API checks the signature and then validates some of the JWT tokens claims (such as the aud, iss, exp etc).

I have read about the **state** and **nonce** parameters, which are sent initially to Azure as a way to increase security, but I am confused between the role of the two.

I want to set the nonce as the client secret, and then verify the claim when it comes back inside the ID Token (step 5).

Is the right way to do it? From what I've read you other use the JWT signature verification & validation OR the Client ID / Client Secret technique, but why can't I use both as in my example when the **nonce** is the **secret**.

Secondly, if I use the nonce for this, what should I used the **state** parameter for? Should I build the state as a random string created by the SPA (so the frontend).

**UPDATE:** Upon further reading, I realized that you **CANNOT** use the Client Secret as the nonce, because the entire idea of the nonce is to be unique each and every time. A nonce is in fact a word created and used just one time, after which it is discarded. Seeing as the Client Secret is always the same, it wouldn't mitigate "replay attacks".

I'll keep this post as I still have the following questions:

1. Is nonce used for the API/Backend to check and state is used by the Client/Browser (e.g. frontend)?
2. What should I do with the Client Secret? It seems to be useless now. Should I add it as an encrypted custom claim?

**FINAL UPDATE:**
Besides the accepted answer, please read about Implicit Flow, Auth Code Flow, ID Tokens and Access tokens and the difference between them to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Don't implement the protocol, use a library

The best (and easiest) way to implement this securely is to not implement it yourself. Instead, use a trustworthy and well-maintained client library which implements the protocol, leaving you free to focus on the value your app is bringing, rather than on the details of the protocol.

In your case, I would recommend using the [Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) (MSAL.js). The [quickstart for MSAL.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript-auth-code) is a good place to start.

## 2. For SPAs, use the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE

You're trying to implement the Implicit Grant flow from a JavaScript application. Instead, you should switch to using the Authorization Code flow (with PKCE). To do this correctly, you will need to deal with a "code verifier" and a "code challenge" and do some hashing. Instead, you should just use a library (see #1, above).

The latest version of MSAL.js implements the Authorization Code Grant flow with PKCE, and you don't have to deal with this at all.

## 3. No, do not use the client secret as the nonce.

(Edit was just added, so I won't go into the details of why not.)

> Is nonce used for the API/Backend to check and state is used by the Client/Browser (e.g. frontend)?

No, both are used by the client (in your case, the JavaScript app). (In many/most cases, the single-page JavaScript app doesn't send the ID token to its backend, it sends the *access* token (which will not contain the nonce), so the backend never sees the state *or* the nonce.)

> What should I do with the Client Secret? It seems to be useless now. Should I add it as an encrypted custom claim?

No, don't do that.

For starters, no part of your JavaScript app should have any long-term secret in it (such as the client secret). Remember that anybody who can load the app can look at the code for your app, and see all the traffic between your app and any backend server it calls. If this communication includes a secret, then any user of your app can see that secret.

If you have no use for your client secret, then you just don't need a client secret. For a public client application (which is what you seem to be building), it is normal that you don't need a client secret.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am quite confused.

1. I didn't want to use MSAL because I thought that is a library that handles authentication for pages with no Backend, and when I mean backend, I mean an API. Perhaps, you refer to SPA's that don't call any API's so they must rely on themselves for the authentication part. 
   After reading about Auth flow vs Implicit flow, it is starting to make some sense.

2. The thing is, I login users in the backend via JWT tokens that are generated by my App. I don't understand how to combine auth flow with azure and my own users.

Comment: Did you look at the quickstart I linked to in my answer? This shows how to use MSAL to have the user sign in, and then obtain an access token to call an API. In the example the API is Microsoft Graph, but that could also be your own API.

Comment: Yeah, apologies, after reading the quickstart and auth flow, I better understand the differences between the two. The Graph part was confusing me. 

One final question, in which case would implicit flow be useful?. Right now, it seems that the implicit flow was the old way of doing things and is deprecated and auth code flow is the more recent, more secure one. Is that correct?